# Ранее работавшие скрипты python имеющие "import random" перестали работать

Tags: python, ubuntu

Ранее работавшие скрипты на Ubuntu 16.04 как python2 так и python3,  имеющиe в шапке `import random` перестали работать, выдают одну и ту же ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "password.py", line 3, in <module>
    import random
  File "/home/user/bin/random.py", line 5, in <module>
    random.shuffle(new_list)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'shuffle'
```

приведен ответ после запуска скрипта, в котором нет вообще 'shuffle'

Как устранить? 
спасибо

Comment: Не называйте ваши скрипты так же как называются стандартные модули. Переименуйте ваш random.py (лежащий в директории `/home/user/bin/`) во что-то другое, и все заработает.

Comment: спасибо, заработало. тупанул